# Href não funciona

Tags: html

Bom, eu estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma e queria que ao clicarem no botao "Ver" fosse para o google, porém não está a ir para o google e depois de eu clicar o site fica http://meusite.com/meuarquivo.php? com um ponto de interrogação no final.

Código Total:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forms | Bootstrap 3.x Admin Theme</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Admin Theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-admin-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-admin-theme-change-size.css">

    <!-- Vendors -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/datepicker.fixes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="vendors/uniform/themes/default/css/uniform.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/uniform.default.fixes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="vendors/chosen.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="vendors/selectize/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core-b3.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="bootstrap-admin-with-small-navbar">
    <!-- small navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bootstrap-admin-navbar-sm" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left bootstrap-admin-theme-change-size">
                            <li class="text">Change size:</li>
                            <li><a class="size-changer small">Small</a></li>
                            <li><a class="size-changer large active">Large</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Reminders <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Settings <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Go to frontend <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Username <i class="caret"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- main / large navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bootstrap-admin-navbar bootstrap-admin-navbar-under-small" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".main-navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="about.html">Admin Panel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- left, vertical navbar & content -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- left, vertical navbar -->
            

            <!-- content -->
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="page-header">
                            <h1>Forms</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="panel panel-default bootstrap-admin-no-table-panel">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="text-muted bootstrap-admin-box-title">Form Example</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bootstrap-admin-no-table-panel-content bootstrap-admin-panel-content collapse in">
                                <form class="form-horizontal">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <legend>Form Horizontal</legend>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput">Focused input</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" value="This is focused...">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Uneditable input</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <span class="form-control">Some value here</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="disabledInput">Disabled input</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input class="form-control disabled" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="Disabled input here..." disabled="">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="optionsCheckbox2">Disabled checkbox</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="optionsCheckbox2" value="option1" disabled="">
                                                    This is a disabled checkbox
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group has-warning">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputError">Input with warning</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="text" id="inputWarning" class="form-control">
                                                <span class="help-block">Something may have gone wrong</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group has-error">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="text" id="inputError" class="form-control">
                                                <span class="help-block">Please correct the error</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group has-error">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputError">Input group with error</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="text" id="inputError" class="form-control">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="help-block">Please correct the error</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group has-success">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputError">Input with success</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <input type="text" id="inputSuccess" class="form-control">
                                                <span class="help-block">Woohoo!</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group has-success">
                                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="selectError">Select with success</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <select id="selectError" class="form-control">
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                    <option>5</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="help-block">Woohoo!</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="http://google.pt"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</button></a>
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default bootstrap-admin-no-table-panel">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="text-muted bootstrap-admin-box-title">Form Wizard</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bootstrap-admin-no-table-panel-content bootstrap-admin-panel-content collapse in">
                                <div id="rootwizard">
                                    <div class="navbar">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Step 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput1">Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput1" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput2">Email</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput2" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput3">Phone</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput3" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput4">Address</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput4" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput5">City</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput5" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput6">State</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput6" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput7">Company Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput7" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput8">Contact Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput8" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput9">Contact Phone</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput9" type="text" value="">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="pager wizard">
                                            <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">First</a></li>
                                            <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a></li>
                                            <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Last</a></li>
                                            <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a></li>
                                            <li class="next finish" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:;">Finish</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- footer -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <footer role="contentinfo">
                        <p class="left">Bootstrap 3.x Admin Theme</p>
                        <p class="right">&copy; 2013 <a href="http://www.meritoo.pl" target="_blank">Meritoo.pl</a></p>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-admin-theme-change-size.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/wysihtml5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/core-b3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard-for.bootstrap3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/boostrap3-typeahead/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            $('.uniform_on').uniform();
            $('.chzn-select').chosen();
            $('.selectize-select').selectize();
            $('.textarea-wysihtml5').wysihtml5({
                stylesheets: [
                    'vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails-b3/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-wysihtml5/wysiwyg-color.css'
                ]
            });

            $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
                'nextSelector': '.next',
                'previousSelector': '.previous',
                onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var $current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
                    $('#rootwizard').find('.progress-bar').css('width', $percent + '%');
                    // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
                    if ($current >= $total) {
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').hide();
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').show();
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').removeClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').hide();
                    }
                },
                onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var $current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
                    $('#rootwizard').find('.progress-bar').css('width', $percent + '%');
                    // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
                    if ($current >= $total) {
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').hide();
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').show();
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').removeClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
                        $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').hide();
                    }
                },
                onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var $current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
                    $('#rootwizard').find('.bar').css({width: $percent + '%'});
                }
            });
            $('#rootwizard .finish').click(function() {
                alert('Finished!, Starting over!');
                $('#rootwizard').find('a[href*=\'tab1\']').trigger('click');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Código a que me refiro:

```html
  <a href="http://google.pt"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</button></a>
```

Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você está usando Bootstrap, acho que esse é o melhor caminho para fazer um botão:

```
<a href="http://google.pt" class="btn btn-default">Ver</a>
```

Mas se vai usar campo de pesquisa, precisa de algo assim:

```
<form action="http://google.pt/search" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="q">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</button>
```

Sem usar `a`. O segredo está em por o endereço no `action` do `form`.

Lembre-se de adequar o `method` para `get` ou  `post` conforme o serviço utilizado.

Comment: No caso funcionou, mas os inputs type submit não funcionam.

Comment: Os inputs de type submit ficam com o ponto de interrogação e não funcionam.

Comment: Vou editar, para você poder experimentar.

Comment: Já não é necessário, o problema foi mesmo esse, esqueci de colocar o action no form original, e criei um novo form.

Comment: Problema Resolvido!

Comment: No caso da pesquisa do Google, o action é `https://www.google.pt/search`, o método é `get` e o nome do parâmetro é `q`. Se for pesquisar imagens, precisa acrescentar um parâmetro `tbm` com valor `isch`